# Do not understand how c++ set works

Tags: c++, set

I am using the `std::set` class for a leetcode question. From Googling I learned that `std::set` keeps the elements in an ordered manner and I heard that `set.begin()` returns the smallest element. But I also heard set uses red-black trees and has O(log n) time complexity. I don't understand how these two can go together, as in how does `set.begin()` return smallest element when a red-black tree doesn't guarantee the smallest element will be the head.

Also `set.begin()` function makes it seem like this container uses an array instead of a linked list to build the redblack tree, which again I don't understand. How can an array be used instead of a tree?

Comment: What makes you think that `set::begin()` would return the root of the tree? Also, how exactly does `set::begin()` makes it look like an array to you? As a side note: trees actually can be represented with array as an implicit data structure (explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation)).

Comment: `set::begin()` simply implies that the set can be put into some kind of *sequence* and that you can iterate over that sequence. That's true of an array as well, but thinking that means a set must be an array is just a logic error. It's usually a red-black tree as you say.

Comment: A `set` can simply keep an iterator to the smallest element to fulfil the constant complexity of `begin`.

Comment: @r3musn0x I can understand the heap representation in an array since its always balanced but from my understanding redblack trees can have imbalances up to a certain level, wouldn't that make it hard to represent as an array?

Comment: @john yes now it makes sense. I assumed begin would point to the root of the tree since thats where the tree "begins" from.

Answer (score 2):

In the underlying tree, the leftmost node is the smallest, and `begin()` is the leftmost node.

Iterating traverses the tree's nodes in the appropriate order.

For instance, if the tree is (this is a simpler "regular" binary search tree, but the principle is the same with red-black trees)

```
     4
   /   \
  2     6
 /\    /
1  3  5
```

then iterating will start at 1, then move up to 2, down again to 3, up two steps to 4, down two steps to 5, and finally up to 6.
(This means that the "steps" when iterating over a tree are not constant-time operations.)

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not impose a particular implementation for any of the containers. A red-black tree is a *possible* implementation of `set`. It's also free to choose how to make `begin` constant complexity.

Assuming the implementation chooses a tree, the most obvious way is by keeping a pointer to the least element, as well as to the root of the tree.

You can implement an ordered set with an array, e.g. [`boost::flat_set`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx). That doesn't meet all the same complexity requirements as `std::set`. It does this by only inserting into the sorted position, and only if there isn't an equivalent element already present.